# How can I sort / etc / network / interfaces?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new at this and I need to order loopback, static, dhcp using the /etc/network/interfaces file as follows for static address:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.11.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.11.1
```

It would look like this:

```
Interface=eth1, Type=Static, Direction=192.168.11.3, Mask=255.255.255.0, Gateway=192.168.11.1
```

For dhcp address:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

It would look like this:

```
Interface=eth0, Type=Dhcp
```

For loopback:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

It would look like this:

```
Interface=lo, Type=loopback
```

I try to solve it as below but it doesn't work

```
if [ grep -r "static" /etc/network/interfaces ]; then
     gawk '{print "Interface=" $2 ", " "Type=" "Static" ", " "Direction=" $2 ", " "Mask=" $2 ", " "Gateway=" $2}' /etc/network/interfaces
```

Comment: The output of grep command is one line,  like "iface eth1 inet static" and it does not contain address, netmask, etc
You can take a look at https://github.com/JoeKuan/Network-Interfaces-Script the set awk scripts that deal with  /etc/network/interfaces